# Another challenge in String Manipulation

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I've to manage the data into this and it has blank space in between:

```
0297144600-4799 0297485500-5599
0297144600-0297144799 0297485500-5599

0297144600-0297144799 0297485500-0297485599
```

I want to normalise the first/2nd row like the last row which means

```
0297144600-4799 >> 0297144600-0297144799
```

The challenge is that it can be on this format: 0297144600-4799 or already normalised and these entries can be more than 2 series for instance:

```
0297144600-4799 0297485500-5599 0297486500-6599
```

But always seperating by blank space (theoritically it can be replaced with '|' if you want). I do have a split method to do is but now how to combining this.

Try to avoid the cursor if it's possible.

Thanks

Comment: I could swear that you posted a split function days ago...

Comment: That split function it works nicely BUT the challenge now the data is not "normalised" somehow. The format needs to be 0297144600-0297144799 (10 digits seperating by another 10 digits)

Comment: What are you actually asking please? Show us some intermediate steps or line by line working: your question makes no sense.

Comment: So what you want to do is a) split each line on a space; b) split each pair on a dash; c) if the second of the pair is four characters then append the first six characters of the first pair?

Comment: Could you please explain more in detail or confirm @Yellowfog's assumption? Thanks

Comment: Where is your split function?  I can try to implement that into an alternative answer (to the one I posted earlier).

Answer (score 0):

Is this something like what you had in mind?

```
declare @table table (old_pair nvarchar(21), new_pair nvarchar(21), pair_left nvarchar(10), pair_right nvarchar(10))

declare @abnormal nvarchar(max)
set @abnormal = isnull('0297144600-0297144799 0297485500-0297485599','')
--set @abnormal = isnull('0297144600-4799 0297485500-5599','')
--set @abnormal = isnull('0297485500-5599','')

declare @pair nvarchar(max)
declare @pair_left nvarchar(10)
declare @pair_right nvarchar(10)
declare @pair_right_length int

WHILE len(isnull(@abnormal,'')) > 0
BEGIN
    IF charindex(' ', @abnormal) = 0
        BEGIN
            set @pair = @abnormal
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            set @pair = left(@abnormal, charindex(' ', @abnormal)-1)
        END
    set @pair_left = left(@pair, 10)
    set @pair_right_length = len(right(@pair,len(@pair)-11))
    set @pair_right = left(@pair_left, 10-@pair_right_length) + right(@pair,len(@pair)-11)

    insert @table
    (   old_pair,
        new_pair,
        pair_left,
        pair_right  )
    select 
        @pair, 
        @pair_left + '-' + @pair_right,
        @pair_left, 
        @pair_right

    IF @pair = @abnormal
        BEGIN
            set @abnormal = (right(@abnormal, len(@abnormal)-len(@pair)))
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            set @abnormal = (right(@abnormal, len(@abnormal)-(len(@pair)+1)))
        END
END
    select * from @table
```